# Notification about status of the population on BF2 server

Tags: server-administration, battlefield-2

Is there a way to monitor a dedicated Battlefield 2 server that would ping via cell-phone text message, e-mail, Twitter, FaceBook or otherwise communicate that there are players on the server? Preferably, something that can be adjusted to be triggered by a certain amount of players (minimum of four, for instance).

This is needed for a community of players to be more aware of the server status without wasting time loading a game, sitting on the server waiting for people to show up, or checking GameTracker or similar services repeatedly. If that matters, it is for [Forgotten Hope 2](http://forgottenhope.warumdarum.de/) mod — fairly popular in Europe, but with very fragmented North and South American player base, and we would like to see if there is tool to keep people informed and increase attendance at least couple of nights a week.

Note: I do not need particular software recommendation, but rather generic explanation of how can it be accomplished (perhaps, exampled with how other games dealt with the issue).

Comment: Voting to reopen. I don't think this is off-topic as per the [meta] posts: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/is-mod-rec-really-am-umbrella-category-that-we-want-to-use-or-is-it-confusing and http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5547/closed-mod-recommendation-skyrim-question-can-this-question-be-improved-and

Comment: @galacticninja Those are mod rec questions.  This is a straight up software recommendation; even with the edit asking for generic explanation, as that'll just garner, "Use program X!"

Comment: @theUg If this doesn't get reopened, you might want to appeal this question's closure at [meta]. Make sure to mention in your post that this is not off-topic as per the Arqade Meta posts I've mentioned in my comment above. I disagree with fbueckert's view that this is a "straight up" software recommendation, nor do I agree that software recommendations per se are off-topic, for reasons mentioned in those meta posts.

Comment: This question should probably be reopened as per this meta post: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6962/why-was-a-question-about-minecraft-server-backup-closed-considering-there-is-a